# HTML Canvas Blendings for different Images

Tags: image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to define different blending mode for different image as like layers:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var image1_ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image1_obj = new Image();
image1_obj.onload = function(){
    image1_ctx.drawImage(image1_obj,0,0) ;
} ;
image1_obj.src = "../img/one.jpg" ;

var image2_ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image2_obj = new Image();
image2_obj.onload = function(){
    image2_ctx.drawImage(image2_obj,0,0) ;
} ;
image2_obj.src = "../img/two.png" ;

var image3_ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image3_obj = new Image();
image3_obj.onload = function(){
    image3_ctx.drawImage(image3_obj,0,0) ;
} ;
image3_obj.src = "../img/three.jpg" ;
image3_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply" ;

var image4_ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image4_obj = new Image();
image4_obj.onload = function(){
    image4_ctx.drawImage(image4_obj,0,0) ;
} ;
image4_obj.src = "../img/four.jpg" ;
image4_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen" ;
```

But last definition of "globalCompositeOperation" is overwriting befores.
Does it possible define it different for each image?

Answer (score 2):

There is only 1 context per canvas element so when your code does `.getContext` it is always fetching the same one-and-only context.

If you want to apply different `globalCompositeOperation`s to different images, you will have to put each `globalCompositeOperation` just before their `drawImage`.

But...

It's possible that you will have race conditions when loading your images so you will probably want to preload all your images before doing the compositing & drawing.